# mod_rewrite setting for CakePHP (shared hosting two domains)

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

I am running into an infinite redirection loop when setting up CakePHP on a bluehost server.

I have set my .htaccess as follows,

1. Under /home/mysite/public_html/site2 (I have configured an add-on domain with site2 as its serving directory on BlueHost)

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
      RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>`
2. Under /home/mysite/public_html/site2/app as,

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
      RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>`
3. And finally under /home/mysite/public_html/site2/app/webroot as,

   `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>`

If I remove the two RewriteCond from the .htaccess under webroot the Cake controllers start working but I don't see any images or CSS. I am not sure where am I going wrong.

Comment: You need to put a line RewriteBase /site2/ in public_html/site2/.htaccess and public_html/site2/app/webroot/.htaccess

Comment: tried that ...but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**creat a htaccess  in root same as**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.tld[NC]
RewriteRule    ^$ site2/app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.tld[NC]
RewriteRule    (.*) site2/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`
```

**and htacess in site2 folder must be**

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]

Comment: Works! (btw..did you mean \.com$ where you say .tld) Thanks a lot.

Comment: ya site2\.com[NC] insted of site2\.tld[NC]